# Can I make a package installation skip over errors and exceptions?

Tags: installation, packages

On Sitecore 8.2, I'm trying to do a big content sync to bring my Dev environment up to date with the production environment.

I've created a large package of the entire content node, and I'm trying to install it to Dev and just overwrite everything. My installation is failing with the message

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Is there a way that I can make the installation continue when an error occurs and just skip the current item?

Comment: Could it be that you have Templates missing?  I'd recommend creating individual packages for Templates, Layouts/Renderings, Media, and Content.

Comment: In the past I used SPE to install while the code was wrapped in an event disabler.

Comment: Can you provide the full stacktrace?

Answer (score 3):

### No

Unfortunately is the only answer. I think the above close votes are from people, trying to help you actually solve the Object Reference exception.

But no you cannot. Sitecore does not have an "ignore errors" or "treat errors as warnings" or similar setting when installing packages. You are going to have to isolate the item(s) that are giving you grief and removing them from the package manually (zip) - or find out why they are failing to install on your system (find the root cause of your exception).

Your Sitecore logs will contain a listing of items installed, giving you a decent idea of which items are causing the failure, so you can act on it.